# In azure logic app how to get key and value of url encoded data

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In azure logic app how to get key and value of URL encoded data. I am not finding details regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found way to work with application/x-www-url-formencoded data.

```
{
    "$content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "$content": "<base64EncodedContent>",
    "$formdata": [{
        "key": "key1",
        "value": "value1"
    }
```

to get key in code view `@triggerBody()['$formdata'][0]['key']`.

to get value in code view `@triggerBody()['$formdata'][0]['value']`.

Answer (score 2):

Some content types are supported and work with logic apps, but might require manually retrieving the message body by decoding the `$content`.

For example, suppose you trigger an `application/x-www-url-formencoded` request where `$content` is the [payload encoded](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/113ee640-d0ea-438c-9b53-3d4ed8e709ab/how-to-extract-values-from-a-twilio-post-payload?forum=azurelogicapps) as a `base64` string to preserve all data.

Because the request isn't plain text or JSON, the [request is stored in the action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-content-type) as follows:

```
"$content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"$content": "<Base64EncodedContent>",
"$formdata": [{
    "key": "ToCountry",
    "value": "AU"
}
```

Being this a Form Data Post request, we can use the function `@triggerFormDataValue()` to get each of the properties, e.g. `@triggerFormDataValue(‘Body’)` and `@triggerFormDataValue(‘From’)`.

For more details, you could refer to this [blog](https://pacodelacruzag.wordpress.com/category/logic-apps/).